# ios: How often and where to set AVAudioSession category

Tags: ios, avaudiosession

I have an app where currently I set the AVAudioSession category once in the initialization of a singleton class (probably not the best place):

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
```

The app is registered for background audio and it works fine. But sometimes after the app goes into the background, and returns to the foreground, and goes back to the background, audio abruptly stops.

I'm unclear on how often and which method the audio session should be set in, and I can't find a suggestion in the docs. Should it be in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, or every time the app becomes active in `applicationDidBecomeActive:`, or somewhere else? For what it's worth I do reset it in `handleMediaServicesReset`.